# JavaScript to open Windows Start Menu

Tags: javascript, windows, menu

I'm working on a personal project where I need a button within a browser to open the start menu (the actual menu, not explorer). I'm working in IE9 as I'm aware this probably wont be possible in newer browsers.

I found a VBS and tried to adapt it as follows, unfortunately I cant get it to work, perhaps someone could point out where I'm going wrong

```
<script>
    function SendKeys99() {
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
    WshShell.SendKeys "^{ESC}";
    }
</script>

<input type="image" img src="assets\Start-Button-High-Res.jpg" height="100" width="100" onclick="SendKeys99();"/>
```

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve in the long run? e.g. are you hoping to run other commands/click on programs in the start menu?

Comment: Its a long story... but the short answer is no, I have a script which can run programs, I simply need a button which will open the start menu

Comment: Can you provide more details on the big picture? e.g. can you not just call the script directly? or call it from a PowerShell script? If you need to run this from the web can you host a server that on the backend (e.g. say ASP.Net) directly calls the script you need. PS what language is the script written in that you have... and what does it do? (does it need to run on a "client" PC or can it run on a server instead?...)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that this will not work as you will have very limited access outside of the browser for security reasons.

If you want to automate Windows I would highly recommend using [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) or an actual VB application.

Comment: Indeed, it's not possible to do that.

Comment: Well I've managed to get a similar script to work with opening system application, word, excel etc... so didn't think it would be much of a leap to get this one to work...

Comment: Opening another application (launching) is feasible but it is a "low risk" activity for ActiveX in the browser and thus enabled.  Sending keystrokes to the host OS from a web page is extremely exposed to the chance for "evil" to occur.

Comment: If anyone has any other suggestions other than calling it via keystrokes I'm all ears???